# How to validate email address from a mat input?(Angular Material)

Tags: angular

How can I validate an email address to have an @ sign and a dot without pressing on a button, without a form. I would appreciate any help.

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use pattern and define a regex to validate email address,

```
<input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="enterEmail" name="myEmail" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}" required>
```

Comment: do u know of a way to add a message to this? without having to declare it with a formcontrol tag

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Angular 8, and it has directive [EmailValidator](https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator).

Use with ngModel like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" ngModel email>
<input type="email" name="email" ngModel email="true">
<input type="email" name="email" ngModel [email]="true">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can validate in this way as well

**In your template(.html file):**

```html
<form
  [formGroup]="userForm"
  #formDirective="ngForm"
  (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()"
>
  <div class="form-control">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field">
      <mat-label>Email Address</mat-label>
      <input
        type="text"
        matInput
        formControlName="email"
        class="form-input-field"
        pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}"
      />
      <mat-error *ngIf="userForm.get('email').hasError('required')"
        >Email is required</mat-error
      >
      <mat-error *ngIf="userForm.get('email').hasError('email')"
        >Please enter a valid email address
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>
```

**In your component(.ts file):**

```js
userForm = new FormGroup({
  email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
});
```